# Scrolling with an easing function

Tags: javascript, dom, animation, easing

I wanted to write a function that when invoked, will scroll the page downwards in a smooth fashion.

Comments and criticism welcome. I don't like, for example that determining whether it is done is not based on the scroll position.

```js
const EASING = BezierEasing(0, .1, .1, 1); // Example values.
const DURATION = 1000; // ms.

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', 
  () =>  {
    document.querySelector('#foo')
      .addEventListener('click', onClick, false);
});

function onClick(e) {
  scroll(400); // px.
  e.preventDefault();
  return false;
}

function scroll(distance) {
  var start, travelled, html;

  start = performance.now();
  travelled = 0;
  html = document.querySelector('html');

  (function move(now) {
    var fractionDone, dy, toMove;

    fractionDone = (now-start) / DURATION;

    if((1 - fractionDone) <= 0) {
      return; // Done!
    }

    if(window.scrollY + window.innerHeight 
      === html.offsetHeight) {
      return; // At bottom of page.
    }

    dy = ((EASING.get(fractionDone)) * distance);
    toMove = Math.floor((dy - travelled)); // `scrollBy` only accepts integers.

    if(toMove > 0) {
      window.scrollBy(0, toMove);
      travelled += toMove;
    }

    requestAnimationFrame(move);
  }(start));
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/gre/bezier-easing/master/build.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <a href id="foo">Click Me!</a>
    <script>
      var body = document.querySelector('body');
      for(var x = 0; x < 50; x++) {  
        var div = document.createElement("div"); 
        var text = document.createTextNode(x);
        div.appendChild(text);
        body.appendChild(div);
      }
    </script>
  </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Note that `() =>  { … }` is ECMAScript 6, which may not work in all browsers today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now assuming you simply just want to use standard APIs and ES6 (because from a cross-browser point of view, this code isn't guaranteed to work)...

- `onClick` is unnecessarily pulled out. You can just inline it. Also, I believe `return false` are unnecessary when you already have `preventDefault`. You wouldn't want to prevent bubbling as something else might be delegating their handlers.

  ```
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () =>  {
      document.querySelector('#foo').addEventListener('click', e => {
        event.preventDefault();
        scroll(400);
      }, false);
  });
  ```
- Variable declarations are also unnecessarily separated. It's not like they're defined somewhere in the middle (where you sometimes need to pull them up for visibility).

  ```
  var start = performance.now();
  var travelled = 0;
  var html = document.querySelector('html');
  ```
- Pull out your `move` function from your scroll. What happens is that every call to `scroll`, you're creating `move`.
- I also suggest you schedule you call `requestAnimationFrame` first thing in the callback. That's so your code won't hold up the scheduling of the next frame. Should you want to bail out, you can always use `cancelAnimationFrame`.
- `Math.floor` can be substituted by `| 0` (bitwise or). Under the hood, it transforms the number from float to int, dropping the decimals. It's fast one some engines, but your mileage may vary.
- Your "bail out" conditions can simply be combined:

  ```
  if((1 - fractionDone) <= 0 || window.scrollY + window.innerHeight === html.offsetHeight) return
  ```

Comment: Thanks. Note that `scroll` is only invoked once per user interaction, making the creation of the function-object a small overhead. `move` is indirectly recursive, but does not exhibit the same problem.